# Loading speed - Iframe - Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, iframe

I have an iframe in my page displaying an ad over my header. It has no scroll.

This works fine on desktop and iphone with acceptable loading time, but on ipad it takes 15-20 second to load. The page loads fine, it is just the iframe that use that long time to show up.

Anyone have any idea what the problem can be, and how to solve it?